# How to hide Elmah Server Variable?

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-5, elmah

I have installed Elmah using Nuget and I am wondering how to hide server variables from error page shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can update the error logged in ELMAH before it is persisted like described here: http://blog.elmah.io/removing-sensitive-form-data-before-logging-to-elmah/